# Can i run root shell commands on a non rooted device with system permission?

Tags: android

I am developing a System app. But right now i dont have the System signatures with me. So I am running it as a normal app on a rooted device. I have programmed using root shell coammands. I have not used any Ssytem permission as it throws me an error because of signature mismatch. My question is , when I will have the system signatures and run this as a system app, will I be able to use the same code? Or will i have to rewrite this code by providing system app permissions.

Foe example for installing a thrid party app via my program,

I am using a shell command and not using Package installer permission. There are many other such cases.

Thanks
Utsav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this question after 2 years replying for others. I did try after having System Signature. It the shell commands does work , you dont need package permissions. Once the app is signed along with the System image it becomes a system app , a part of the app, you can do pertty much with shell command without using the permissions.